# How can I set active class to php generated links?

Tags: php, magento, hyperlink

I am working on a side bar for magento that displays sub categories

```
echo '<div id="sidenavcat">';
$object = new Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation();
$actualCategoryId = $object->getCurrentCategory()->getId();
$actualCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($actualCategoryId);
$subCategories = explode(',', $actualCategory->getChildren());

foreach ( $subCategories as $subCategoryId )
{
    $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($subCategoryId);
    if ( $category->getIsActive() )
    {
echo '<li><a href="'.$category->getURL().'" style="text-decoration: none"         class="active">'.$category->getName().'</a> </li>';
    }
}
echo '</div>';
```

How would I go about adding an active class an individual link?

Answer (score 0):

just need to set else part

```
foreach ( $subCategories as $subCategoryId )
{
    $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($subCategoryId);
    if ( $category->getIsActive() )
    {
echo '<li><a href="'.$category->getURL().'" style="text-decoration: none"         class="active">'.$category->getName().'</a> </li>';
    }else{

echo '<li>'.$category->getName().' </li>';
}
}
```

if you want current category then used below code

```
Mage::registry('current_category')->getId();
```

Comment: getIsActive() looks to see if the category is active. Your solution will just show inactive category's.

Answer (score 0):

A simplest solution is to compare if the current url contains the name of the category or the category url key maybe. Then set it as active.